# React Native Android duplicate resources when building with asembleRelease

Tags: reactjs, react-native

"react-native": "0.68.2"

Hi everybody, I'm trying to get .aab file for my react native app but when I use command:

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

I get the following error:

```
Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] C:\xampp\htdocs\Woo\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] C:\xampp\htdocs\Woo\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_images_amaro1] C:\xampp\htdocs\Woo\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_images_amaro1.jpeg  [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_images_amaro1] C:\xampp\htdocs\Woo\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\drawable-mdpi\assets_images_amaro1.jpeg: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_images_applogo] C:\xampp\htdocs\Woo\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_images_applogo.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_images_applogo] C:\xampp\htdocs\Woo\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\drawable-mdpi\assets_images_applogo.png: Error: Duplicate resources
```

Answer (score 0):

I've came across the same error a few days ago.
What a did was to delete all the drawable-* dirs with the command:

```
rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*
```

Or in your case, you can go to the path

```
android/app/src/main/res/
```

And delete them manually.
Then, try to create apk again!